# Summing an already outputted list

Tags: prolog, logic

This is the knowledge base I am working with:

```
localLib('AHorowitz','Stormbreaker',2).
localLib('AHorowitz','Scorpia',4).
localLib('AHorowitz','Ark Angel',6).
```

The key for the knowledge base is as follows:

```
localLib(W,B,C) where
W=Writer
B=Book
C=Acknowledgements
```

**I would like to write a rule that adds up all the acknowledgements of the writer.**
This is the code I have written so far:

```
getAcknowledgement(W,X):- findall(C,localLib(W,_,C),X).
```

This rule helps me list all the acknowledgements in separate list e.g.

```
?- getAcknowledgement('AHorowitz',X). 
X = [2, 4, 6]
```

I am now getting stuck on how to add these items. I know of the **sum_list** built in and though I know it is not correct the thing I want to achieve is this:

```
getAcknowledgement(W,X):- findall(C,localLib(W,_,C),X).

sum_list(X,[getAcknowledgement]). 

/* I would like to sum the output that I receive from the first rule above.
    The KB has been simplified in this example to 3 clauses however in reality 
    there are 1000.*/
```

How would I go about doing this, any help would be great?

Comment: `getAcknowledgement(W, X), sum_list(X, S).`

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was almost there!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to find the count of acknowledgements by writer.

[`bagof/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3) is your friend here. It

> - `bagof(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)`
>
>   Unify *Bag* with the alternatives of *Template*. If *Goal* has free variables besides the one
>     sharing with *Template*, `bagof/3` will backtrack over the alternatives of these free
>     variables, unifying *Bag* with the corresponding alternatives of *Template*. The construct
>     `+Var^Goal` tells `bagof/3` not to bind *Var* in *Goal*. `bagof/3` fails if *Goal* has no
>     solutions.

[`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) is

> equivalent to `bagof/3` with all free variables bound with the existential operator (`^`),
>   except that `bagof/3` fails when *Goal* has no solutions.

So...this should get you the summed count of knowledgements for a given writer, or, if `Writer` is unbound, on backtracking, it will find the solutions for *all* writers, one at a time.

```
acknowledgements_by_writer( Writer , Acknowledgements ) :-
  bagof( N , local_lib(Writer,_,N) , Ns ) ,
  sum_list(Ns,Acknowledgments).
```

If you want the overall count of acknowledgements, something like this ought to do you

total_acknowledgements(T) :-
     findall(N,local_lib(*,*,N),Ns),
     sum_list(Ns,T).